# Could not find composer version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

Tags: git, github, composer-php, bitbucket

I reviewed all questions and solutions in stack overflow. But I failed to resolve this issue. Error Message :

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package selimppc/hello-world at any version for your
minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

Here is my `composer.json` file ::

```
{
"name": "Hello worlds Apps",
"description": "New Apps from SelimReza.com",
"type": "library",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [{
    "name": "Selim Reza",
    "email": "me@selimreza.com"
}],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "selimppc/hello-world": "@dev"
},

"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "HelloWorld\\": "src\\HelloWorld\\"
    }
}
}
```

Github URL : `https://github.com/selimppc/hello-world`

I can't imagine solution for this error. Also Please let me know the way to resolve and causes for this one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

dev-master is not a valid stability:

Available options (in order of stability) are dev, alpha, beta, RC, and stable.

See:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

Also the package cannot refer to itself, you will have to change the name in your package.json.

If I change the name and the min-stability to dev. It works.

You won't need the repositories, they also refer to themself

```
{
"name": "some/new-name",
"description": "New Apps from SelimReza.com",
"type": "library",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [{
"name": "Selim Reza",
"email": "me@selimreza.com"
}],
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.6",
   "selimppc/hello-world": "dev-master"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,

"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "HelloWorld\\": "src\\HelloWorld\\"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I did for `dev` too .. but still same error @Torsten

Comment: @Tosten : I did not understand  `the package cannot refer to itself,`. Would you please elaborate little more ?

Comment: The second line: {
"name": "selimppc/hello-world",

just change the name

Comment: same error : ` [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package selimppc/hello-world at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability`

Comment: well it worked fine on my workstation.
try  composer clearcache.

Somewhere ist the min-stability set to stable, as you can see in you error message

Comment: `composer require selimppc/hello-world:dev-master` is working ?? @Torsten

Comment: okay see your point. I did composer install. 

In order to call it  with composer require, you need to register it add packigist under the new name.

Comment: would you please have a look :: `https://github.com/selimppc/hello-world`